# What other math fields wouldn't require learning a huge amount of material in advance?

Tags: reference-request, big-list

From [*An Introduction to the Theory of Surreal Numbers*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521312051):

> [...] Thus the reader has the opportunity which is all too rare
>   nowadays of getting to the surface and tackling interesting original
>   problems without having to learn a huge amount of material in
>   advance.

What other math fields would be in the same class as this one? What other math fields wouldn't require learning a huge amount of material in advance and would allow one to tackle interesting original problems?

Comment: Well, pretty much by definition: Any subject taught in first or second year university.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I edited the question.

Comment: Some areas of combinatorics can be quite accessible (though its still no cakewalk). Perhaps someone with more knowledge can comment on this.

Comment: In my experience, most anything in linear algebra. For example, many data compression techniques require a relatively elementary knowledge of linear algebra, yet are very interesting, and have powerful results. Many such techniques still have open questions regarding the limits of simplifying their computational complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ramsey theory on the integers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821831992) has research problems in every chapter (presumably still open) and I think it's pretty accessible to most levels.